# Hey i am making a social media app and want to save a post to my db. but i keep get getting the error

Tags: python, database, flask, sqlalchemy

sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: blogpost [SQL: 'INSERT INTO blogpost (title, author, date_posted, content) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)'] [parameters: ('qedqdq', 'qwdqdwd', '2018-12-31 22:51:35.669388', 'qwdqwdqwdqwdqwdqwdqwdqwdw')] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)

After i send the post to get published in my database i get ^^ the error

here are some of the code i am using.

Any help would be great thanks!!!

app.py

```
import os  
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for  
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)  

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL'] = 'sqlite:///Users/------/Desktop/face0/face/blog.db'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Blogpost(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(50))
    author = db.Column(db.String(20))
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    content = db.Column(db.Text)

@app.route('/addpost', methods=['POST'])
def addpost():
    title = request.form['title']
    author = request.form['author']
    content = request.form['content']

    post = Blogpost(title=title, author=author, content=content, date_posted=datetime.now())

    db.session.add(post)
    db.session.commit()

    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the [flask-sqlalchemy documentation](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/quickstart/), you will need to first create the database by calling the `create_all` function.

> To create the initial database, just import the db object from an
>   interactive Python shell and run the SQLAlchemy.create_all() method to
>   create the tables and database:

```
>>> from yourapplication import db
>>> db.create_all()
```

In your case this may look something like the following:

```
$ python
>>> from app import db
>>> db.create_all()
>>> exit()
```